# Integration (Trapezium Rule)

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm new to trapezium rule. How can I use trapezium rule with 4 intervals to find approximation for $\int_{0}^{1.6}xe^{x^2}$.

Determine whether over or under estimate the exact value by using trapezium rule.
Give a sketch of $y=xe^{x^2}$, give reason to the shape of graph.

My attempt,

Trapezoidal rule states that $$\displaystyle{\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx}\approx\frac{\Delta{x}}{2}\left(f(x_0)+2f(x_1)+2f(x_2)+...+2f(x_{n-1})+f(x_n)\right)$$, where $$\displaystyle{\Delta{x}=\frac{b-a}{n}}$$
$$a=0, b=\frac{8}{5}, n=4$$

Therefore, $$\displaystyle{\Delta{x}=\frac{\frac{8}{5}-0}{4}}=\frac{2}{5}$$
Divide $$\left[0,\frac{8}{5}\right]$$ into $$n=4$$ sub intervals of length $$\Delta{x}=\frac{2}{5}$$ with the following endpoints: $$a=0, \frac{2}{5}, \frac{4}{5}, \frac{6}{5}, \frac{8}{5}=b$$

$$f(x_{0})=f(a)=f(0)=0=0$$
$$2f(x_{1})=2f(\frac{2}{5})=\frac{4 e^{\frac{4}{25}}}{5}=0.938808696793448$$
$$2f(x_{2})=2f(\frac{4}{5})=\frac{8 e^{\frac{16}{25}}}{5}=3.03436940688792$$
$$2f(x_{3})=2f(\frac{6}{5})=\frac{12 e^{\frac{36}{25}}}{5}=10.1296699607917$$
$$f(x_{4})=f(b)=f(\frac{8}{5})=\frac{8 e^{\frac{64}{25}}}{5}=20.6973077048689$$

$$\frac{\Delta{x}}{2}=\frac{1}{5}$$:

$$\frac{1}{5}(0+0.938808696793448+3.03436940688792+10.1296699607917+20.6973077048689)=6.96003$$

Comment: It would be better to show your own efforts to solve the problem. This community is not designed to solve homeworks for free.

Comment: You could use search and find similar questions, such as http://math.stackexchange.com/q/124050/

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I've edited the post

Comment: its exact value is 5.96791. @Amzoti

Comment: Actually the direction of the error should be clear enough when this is graphed. The amount of the error is not so clear without calculation.

Comment: The question asks me to give reason to the graph. @Amzoti I don't know how to answer.

Comment: You know that TRAP calculates the sum of the areas of $4$ trapezoids. If we *think* about the second derivative of $xe^{x^2}$ (don't really need to calculate), we see that the second derivative is positive so the curve is concave up. That means that the approximating trapezoids are larger than the corresponding area under the curve. So TRAP gives an overestimate.